# Unable to execute multiple commands + nested if in a for loop over ssh non-interactive session

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to run certain commands, also checking some using nested if conditions over non-interactive SSH connections to my servers in the list. But unfortunately, it hits with syntax errors.

```
$ for i in $(cat servers);do ssh -t -l root ${i} 'hostname && grep BACKUPENABLE /var/cpanel/backups/config && if [[ $(ss -tulnp | grep rpc) ]] ; then echo -ne "RPCbind service is running \n$(cat /etc/exports)\n"; IP=$(awk -F'(' '{print $1}' /etc/exports | awk '{print $2}'); if [[ $( ping ${IP} -c1 > /dev/null) ]] ; then echo "NFS server responds"; else echo "NFS server not responding"; fi ; else -ne "No RPC and NFS backup not found\n"; fi && ss -tulnp | grep -vE "ssh|cpsrvd|pure-ftp|exim|httpd|named|dovecot|mysqld|snmp|ntp|java|spamd|cpdavd|State|rpc" && if [ -x /usr/sbin/csf ]; then echo csf present;else echo csf not present;fi && yum -q check-update kernel' 2> /dev/null;echo;done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

when checking in debug mode

```
$ bash -x for i in $(cat servers);do ssh -t -l root ${i} 'hostname && grep BACKUPENABLE /var/cpanel/backups/config && if [[ $(ss -tulnp | grep rpc) ]] ; then echo -ne "RPCbind service is running \n$(cat /etc/exports)\n"; IP=$(awk -F'(' '{print $1}' /etc/exports | awk '{print $2}'); if [[ $( ping ${IP} -c1 > /dev/null) ]] ; then echo "NFS server responds"; else echo "NFS server not responding"; fi ; else -ne "No RPC and NFS backup not found\n"; fi && ss -tulnp | grep -vE "ssh|cpsrvd|pure-ftp|exim|httpd|named|dovecot|mysqld|snmp|ntp|java|spamd|cpdavd|State|rpc" && if [ -x /usr/sbin/csf ]; then echo csf present;else echo csf not present;fi && yum -q check-update kernel' 2> /dev/null;echo;done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

But the interesting thing is when I run the set of commands on an individual server, it produces the expected result fine.

```
root@server [~]# hostname && grep BACKUPENABLE /var/cpanel/backups/config && if [[ $(ss -tulnp | grep rpc) ]] ; then echo -ne "RPCbind service is running \n$(cat /etc/exports)\n"; IP=$(awk -F'(' '{print $1}' /etc/exports | awk '{print $2}'); if [[ $( ping ${IP} -c1 > /dev/null) ]] ; then echo "NFS server responds"; else echo "NFS server not responding"; fi ; else -ne "No RPC and NFS backup not found\n"; fi && ss -tulnp | grep -vE "ssh|cpsrvd|pure-ftp|exim|httpd|named|dovecot|mysqld|snmp|ntp|java|spamd|cpdavd|State|rpc" && if [ -x /usr/sbin/csf ]; then echo csf present;else echo csf not present;fi && yum -q check-update kernel
server.host.com
BACKUPENABLE: 'no'
RPCbind service is running
/backups/serverpath    IP.x.x.x(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
NFS server not responding
udp    UNCONN     0      0                      *:44892                 *:*
udp    UNCONN     0      0                      *:2049                  *:*
udp    UNCONN     0      0                     :::36718                :::*
udp    UNCONN     0      0                     :::2049                 :::*
tcp    LISTEN     0      64                    :::2049                 :::*
tcp    LISTEN     0      64                     *:2049                  *:*
tcp    LISTEN     0      64                    :::45701                :::*
tcp    LISTEN     0      64                     *:38633                 *:*
csf present

kernel.x86_64                                                                  2.6.32-754.29.1.el6                                                                   updates
```

Basically, I can't figure out where the problem lies. Is it SSH can't group them or break at any point of if conditions instead of running sequentially over a non-interactive session?.

Comment: You have some issues with the quotes in the string. Make sure they are properly set. Your string is terminated in the middle of the loop.

Comment: @Poshi I am sorry but not a complete answer. As you can see, I ran the same command on server directly, which executes fine.

Comment: Nested quotes most probably, You cant nest quotes like that.

Comment: No, it is just a comment, not an answer. I just pinpointed the issue, but I didn't took the work of fully solving the problem: it is easy but time consuming. Your quoting is bad, check it. If you take out quotes and run it directly, it works, which clearly points to an issue with the quotes you have to add in the `ssh`command.

Comment: Put your command inside a script and add a shebang then paste it to https://shellcheck.net that should tell you something.

Comment: Good idea! Shellcheck is putting arrows just where the issue happens. This saves you the burden of having to check word by word.